# URL Encoding on Jetty - Plus becomes Space

Tags: url, jetty, tapestry

I have a URL that has a "+" sign.
localhost:8080/p1?name=Hello+World

Jetty is converting the "+" to space and this comes as "Hello World" to Tapestry, which in turn raises an exception.

How do I allow the "+" in the URL? I am unable to find any definitive approach here.
And no, using %20 is not an option. My client will invoke with the "+" symbol in the URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

KB

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: What version of Tapestry?

Comment: Jetty: 6.1.16, Tapestry: 5.3.7

Comment: I've tried this with Jetty version 9.3 and still face the same issue.

Comment: Edit your question and add the stacktrace that Tapestry produces.  This sort of issue is squarely in the fault of Tapestry, as Jetty is following 3 different specs with regards to this situation (Instances of `%20` in the URL are part of [RFC1738](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738), instances of `+` in the query section satisfy [XHTML 4.0.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, and finally access to Parameters in the Servlet spec are always in decoded form)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joakim. I managed to work around this by using @RequestParameters instead of @ActivationRequestParameter.
For some reason, the former accepts spaces while the latter does not.